# Registry read different in office 2007 64 bit and 2010 32 bit

Tags: c#, com, registry, vsto

I am building a COM addin using the office interops. I have code that reads a license key from the registry. The odd thing is that it reads the license key perfectly in Excel 2007 (64 bit) but then when I run the same piece of code in Excel 2010 (32 bit) the license key is populated as empty string when read from the registry. I am using this code to read the license key:

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Plugin\PluginSubFolder");
return (string)key.GetValue("License", "");
```

I know this issue is kind of vague and could result from a lot of things, but I'm not really sure where to start on debugging this.

Any ideas what could be causing this? I am happy to answer any additional questions about the code or the issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

64 bit processes read a different part of the registry than 32 bit ones do. There is some OS redirection magic going on here.

Best solution is to add the key to both locations.

See [32-bit and 64-bit Application Data in the Registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN for details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick and accurate input. Depending on the program, I had to check in a different place. So I added an additional check in `@"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Plugin\PluginSubFolder"` and it works swimmingly now. Thanks!